# How do you get a count for similar columns on different tables?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Newby to Mysql. I have 2 tables with similar columns that I need a count for. I can do it separately but not in the same statement.

**Table 1 = "Chi_crime_incidents" ,
Table 2 = "Det_crime_incidents"**

They both have columns called **"offense_incidents"**, I would like to count how many of each incident there are for each table. (all in a Join or Union statement/ whatever is needed)

**Current Attempt:**

```
SELECT chi_crime_incidents.offense_category AS chi_offense_category, det_crime_incidents.offense_category as det_offense_category, COUNT(*) AS offense_incidents
FROM chi_crime_incidents
JOIN det_crime_incidents 
ON chi_crime_incidents.offense_category
GROUP BY chi_crime_incidents.offense_category, det_crime_incidents.offense_category
ORDER BY det_crime_incidents.offense_category;
```

Comment: *`ON chi_crime_incidents.offense_category`* - what a strange joining condition? What does it should mean?

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you 2 columns in 1 row:

```
SELECT  ( SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM  chi_crime_incidents
             WHERE ??
        ) AS  Chi_offense_incidents, 
        ( SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM  det_crime_incidents
             WHERE ??
        ) AS  det_offense_incidents ;
```

This gives you 2 columns in 2 rows:

```
SELECT    "Chi_offense_incidents:",
          COUNT(*) AS incidents
    FROM  chi_crime_incidents
    WHERE ??
UNION ALL
SELECT    "Det_offense_incidents:",
          COUNT(*) AS incidents
    FROM  det_crime_incidents
    WHERE ??
;
```